# Rails won't reload local javascript if redirect from an anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a `foo.js` from `FoosController`. If I enter localhost:3000/foos, then the jquery onready function will be loaded. However, if I click on an `<a href="/foos">` or `link_to`, the jquery onready function won't be loaded. Is there a problem with my configuration? or is this an expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the cause of your problem is turbolinks. Try to disable turbolinks or add a `data-no-turbolink='true'` to your links and check if it works.

More about turbolink and document.ready [here](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/jquery-document-ready-events-and-turbolinks/).

Answer (score 0):

run your code after turbolink:load event:

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', () => {
  // your code
});
```