# rails assets - not working properly on link click, but working when refreshed or pressed enter in address bar. Heroku link provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is link to my app on heroku: http://glacial-temple-5892.herokuapp.com/

It has a dropdown having 4 links, all pointing to the home url.

If you click 'dropdown' first, then dropdown will open and shows 4 links. When one link clicked, it will come to same page(home page with route '/') and then clicking dropdown doesnt work now. But, when we refresh or press enter on address bar, it works.

Whats the solution ?

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assets test</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello </a>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li><a >link</a></li>
        <li><a >link</a></li>
        <li class='dropdown'>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href='/'>link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/'>link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/'>link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/'>link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</nav>
    <p class='notice'><%= notice %></p>
    <p class='alert'><%= alert %></p>
<%= yield %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
</body>
</html>
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives)        for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//=require dropdown
//= require_tree .
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *=require bootstrap
 */
```

I placed bootstrap.css in vendor/stylesheets
I placed dropdown.js in vendor/javascripts/ directory

Comment: You have turbolinks and improperly bound js events for drop down opening. Check either Railscasts or Rails Guides

Answer (score 3):

Check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949106/rails-wont-reload-local-javascript-if-redirect-from-an-anchor-link/18949153#18949153): same problem due to turbolinks which does not trigger Document.ready event.