# Bootstrap navbar dropdowns not always working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3 and am having issues with the dropdown's in my navbar consistently dropping down. I'm finding that they will work from certain pages (landing page) but once I navigate to another page from the navbar the drop down will no longer activate when clicked.

I can supply whatever code would be helpful to identify the problem.

I'm using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem at the bootstrap3 branch.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some code and screenshots that makes the issue more transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to turbolinks which does not trigger the document.ready event.

As i said in an other [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949106/rails-wont-reload-local-javascript-if-redirect-from-an-anchor-link/18949153#18949153), you can disable turbolinks only for one link by adding `data-no-turbolink='true'` to your link tag, or for all you application by simply removing the turbolinks gem.

You also can do a home-made patch: see [here](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/jquery-document-ready-events-and-turbolinks/)

Comment: Thanks Simon, I removed the turbolinks gem and additionally needed to remove the //= require turbolinks from my application.js file.